# Dynamically create a Vue model based on ID

Tags: model, vue.js

I have an input **without** any Vue directives:

`<input type="text" id="name" />`

Now I'm building a custom Vue component that accepts a parameter named `input`, which is expected to be the DOM selector of that input:

`<component input="#name"></component>`

Now I'd like to toggle a class in the component's template based on the value of the input, similar to form input binding. However since we're inside a component I guess model binding cannot be used. So I tried to create a computed property:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="[inputValue ? 'active' : '']"></div>
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: [
            'input'
        ],
        computed: {
            inputValue: function () {
                return $(this.input).val();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. Anyone knows a workaround to watch the "external" input's value in this component?

(note: the main functionality of the component is left out for brevity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM is designed to stop you having to access DOM objects directly via an id, instead you bind them to model data:

```
<input type="text" v-model="name" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
new Vue({
  data: {
     name: ""
   }
});
</script>
```

You can then pass the data to your component as a prop:

```
<component :input="name"></component>
```

Now you have the data, which you can use instead:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="[isActive() ? 'active' : '']"></div>
</template>

...
methods: {
   isActive : function() {
     return this.input;
   }
}
...
```

**EDIT:**

I just want to point out that I've simply followed your example with `return this.input;`, but this actually will not work unless you convert the value to boolean. It's much better to make sure you only return true or false from the function:

```
   isActive : function() {
     return (this.input == "") ? false: true;
   }
```

Comment: So there's really no way of getting model-like behavior without explicitly defining a form input binding?

Comment: Technically, what you are trying to do is possible, you would need to do something like: `$(this.$parent.$el).find(this.input).val()`, in your `inputValue` computed, but it's not really what vue is intended for.

Comment: Ok. So now I tried the suggested code. Is it possible to retrieve the DOM element of the model so I can attach a hover listener during mounting of the component?

Comment: I don't think you can attach anything to the `parent` from the `child` component, but if you want to get the element in the template itself then it's just `$(this.$el)`